# Simulink Deployment not working eventhough it works well in I/O mode

Tags: matlab, model, simulink

I wish you all have a nice day!
I got a question about Simulink deployment, I built a simulink model with PID block, Arduino I/O from Arduino package, Multiport switch block and it works well in I/O mode. When I change to Built, Deploy and start, after clicking the button, the Diagnostic tell that the model bulit successfully but it's not working as expected. I'm using Arduino Uno R3. Could anyone help me with this problem?

I don't know what to try. Please help me!